# How to avoid refreshing of textbox value in asp.net when click button?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I have  a web form that includes 2 main "div".In first div(DivUser),i have a form that includes textboxes and buttons and in the second div(DivSignature),i get the values from that form and show at the second div when i click on the btn_CreateSignature button in form.
I want to avoid refreshing of the textboxes' value in first div but i want to refresh the second div.
How can i do that?I have added my code below.Please help me about that issue.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="DivUser" class="y-container Outer">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block">
  <ContentTemplate>
           <h5>Hello  <asp:LinkButton ID="lblUserName" ForeColor="Red" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton></h5>
      </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
      <h5><asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="pull-right" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" Font-Underline="True">Log Out</asp:LinkButton> </h5>
        <h2><asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"/> - Update User Information</h2>       
        </div>            
      <div class="form-group row InnerLeft" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:10px;" >
      <div class="form-inline form-group">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label">User Name</label>
  <input class="form-control col-10"  type="text"  id="inputUsername" style="width:22%;font-size:16px;"  runat="server" required="required"/>
          </div>
              <div class="form-inline form-group">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
  <input class="form-control col-10"  type="text"  id="inputName" style="margin-left:75px;width:22%;font-size:16px;" runat="server" required="required"/>
          </div>
              <div class="form-inline form-group">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Surname</label>
  <input class="form-control col-10"  type="text"  id="inputSurname" style="margin-left:48px;width:22%;font-size:16px;" runat="server" required="required"/>
          </div>  
                <div class="form-inline form-group">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
  <input class="form-control col-10"  type="text"  id="inputTitle" style="margin-left:48px;width:42%;font-size:16px;" runat="server" required="required"/>
          </div> 
               <div class="form-inline form-group">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
  <input class="form-control col-10"  type="email"  id="inputEmail" style="margin-left:52px;width:42%;font-size:16px;" runat="server" required="required"/>
          </div> 
             <div class="form-inline form-group">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Phone</label>
  <input class="form-control col-10"  type="tel"  id="inputPhone" style="margin-left:40px;width:22%;font-size:16px;" runat="server" required="required"/>
          </div> 
         <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Update Password</label>           
         <asp:Button   ID="btn_UpdatePassword" class="btn btn-success"  runat="server" OnClick="btn_UpdatePassword_Click" Text="Update Password"/> 
           <p /><br />
          <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Create Signature</label>           
         <asp:Button   ID="btn_CreateSignature" class="btn btn-warning leftmargin"   runat="server" OnClick="btn_CreateSignature_Click" Text="Create Signature"/> 
          <p /><br />
           <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Update_Click" />&nbsp;
           <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btn_Cancel_Click" runat="server"/>
                </div>
            <div class="InnerRight" style="width:425px;height:260px;">
                             <div id="divSignature" class="x-container" style="margin-top:10px;padding-top:10px; width:425px;height:260px;background-color:White;">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <img style="width: 140px" src="images/logo_signature.png"/>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 15px">
                <div class="x-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div>
                            <div class="x-container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h5>
                                     <strong><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" style="font-family:'Times New Roman'"></asp:Label></strong>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top: -10px">
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" style="font-family:'Times New Roman'"></asp:Label>                
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <hr style="margin-top: -10px;"/>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top: -15px">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>M&nbsp;:</strong><p> <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" style="font-family:'Times New Roman'"></asp:Label></p>
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>T&nbsp;&nbsp;: </strong><p style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">  +00 000 00 00</p>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>E &nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong><p> <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" style="font-family:'Times New Roman'"></asp:Label> </p>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
                                            <p>
                                                <strong>W:&nbsp;</strong><p style="font-family:'Times New Roman'"> www.website.com</p>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 1px;font-size:12px;">
            <div class="x-container">
                <div class="row">
                        <div style="align-self: center;font-family:'Times New Roman'" >
                             Address<br/>
                        </div>      
                        <div style="margin-left: 15px;">
                                <img width="70" src="images/qr_code.png"/>    
                        </div>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px" >
                <img style="width: 400px" src="images/seritt.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First change the

```
<input>
```

tags to

```
<asp:textbox id="controlID" runat="server">
```

now in the .cs (or .vb) file you will save all the values of these textbox to a session state.

```
Session["SessionName"] = textBox1.Text;
```

And after that you will fill the controls in the Page_Load method:

```
if(!isPostBack){
 textBox1.Text = Session["SessionName"];
}
```

You can, if you have more than one TextBox  store the values in an array and then store the array in a session.

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you @Levidoom,but my first values of textboxes come from database and if i use session state in the Page_Load method,how can i get the values from the database at first page load?

Comment: @Hasan Veil I edited the answer and found my mistake. Make sure that you put !isPostBack this will be called only after you use any kind of control that causes a post back event. The problem with web applications is that once you call a postBack event you get a new aspx document and you can't store info in it but that is where sessions come in. Before the postBack is triggered you store all data you want to save to a session and before the page is fully loaded (Page_Load) you put the values in the text boxes using the session

Comment: You should read up on web application life cycles to get a better understanding on these thing. It's actually very simple once you get a hang of it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx